# No audio in Firefox, Chrome, Spotify, etc. on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, pulseaudio, hdmi

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and I'm having some issues with my audio. I have an Intel H61 Express chipset and I'm using the HDMI out to my home theatre system.

- When I select the HDMI device in System Settings and click Test
  Speaker, it only works the second time. Someone suggested that the
  HDMI may not have had time to sync the first time.
- Audio works fine through XBMC.
- Audio works fine when typing "aplay -D default test.wav"
- Audio does **NOT** work in Chrome, Firefox, Rhythmbox, Spotify, etc.

Does anyone have an ideas what this could be? I've tried resetting pulseaudio and following many of the other similar answers on this site but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Should also note that the audio not working in browsers is happening on both HTML5 and Flash

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b5a446b15448fc38ef084c46e8adc81f0d50a46

Comment: what audio are you trying to play ? flash ? html5 ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Both flash and HTML5 have this problem.

After doing a lot of experimenting, it looks like the sound will work in other applications if something like XBMC is keeping the HDMI audio stream active. The browser itself will not open the HDMI audio stream to start playing unless XBMC is open. Is there some type of fix or script I can run to keep that HDMI audio channel open all the time like Windows would?

Comment: Sounds as if it is a configuration issue. Try pavucontrol or alsamixer or set your default device perhaps.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Did both of those already. I posted my Alsa debug file above. The devices are unmuted and set as default. Again - they work as long as some other application (ie. XBMC) is holding the HDMI auto stream open, but they will not open it on their own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: any apparmor errors ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Not sure where I'd find those... `cat /var/log/syslog | grep apparmor` returns nothing.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor#Debugging_procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the adobe-flashplugin:

```
apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin
```